# How to write azure functions which will use express api

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have a azure function,
In index.js i have the following code

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {

const createHandler = require('azure-function-express').createHandler;
const app = require('express')();

app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
    const y = { "name": "name", "dob": "ddmmyyyy" }
    context.res = y
    context.done()
});
module.exports = createHandler(app);

context.done();
};
```

i have function.json :

```
    {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "{*segments}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

i have the above files in my azure function but i am not able get any output i just a blank page if i hit the api end point.
i have to use express to handle many other end points is there any way to handle in azure functions.

when i use nodejs local application setup, i am able to use express and handle many api end points with in a single module is that possible in azure functions? or i have to use different  functions for each end point

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See code below. We can use Azure function as a common express app.

```
const createHandler = require('azure-function-express').createHandler;
const app = require('express')();

app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ "name": "name", "dob": "ddmmyyyy" });
});

app.get("/work", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ "name": req.query.name, "dob": "ddmmyyyy" });
});

module.exports = createHandler(app);
```

`module.exports = function (context, req)` and `context.done()` are no longer useful if `azure-function-express` is in use. If you want to use other method of context, use req.context instead. See [azure-function-express module doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-function-express).

Besides, Azure function has a prefix "api" in route by default, if you don't need it(like code above), change it to empty your `host.json`.

If your function runtime is ~2(beta).

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
        "routePrefix": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Else in ~1

```
{
    "http": {
        "routePrefix": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it still possible and common to use Express.js in a Node.js Azure Function using the v4 programming model?  I am new to Azure Functions and still trying to figure out how they should be structured and what code is considered ‘normal’ to use in an Azure Function.

Answer (score 1):

I have also use try this **azure-function-express** package but its still in the development and need a-lot of improvement. The best package i found is [Azure AWS Severless Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-aws-serverless-express)

Package. Its very easy to use and compatible. You can easily use the Express with azure functions